# primeNG Checkbox onchange method is not getting triggered

Tags: html, angular, primeng

We are using PrimeNG checkbox to select and unselect products, In desktop selecting and unselecting it is working fine, in the Ipad while selecting checkbox **onChange** is getting called, In the case of unselecting checkbox **onChange** method is not getting triggered.
Could anyone explain why it is not working?

```
<p-checkbox [style]="{'padding-left':'0px'}"
            [name]="product.name"
            binary="true"
            [disabled]="product.disabled || disabled || _disconnectModel.disable() || (disableIfBulkCustomerInQcPage() &&  product?.primaryServiceUnit !='MOBILE')"
            [(ngModel)]="product.selected"
            (onChange)="updateProducts('check', product)"
            id="custom-checkbox"
            (mouseenter)="showOp(product)" pTooltip="{{prodDetails_popUp}}"
            esLoggingChange [logData]="getEsLogData('Checkbox', product)"></p-checkbox>
```

Comment: You are not using PrimeFaces.